# AWS:Invoking bedrock client from boto3 throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-bedrock

I am getting issues while invoking bedrock-runtime service from boto3.

Code:

```
client = boto3.client(service_name='bedrock-runtime',region_name='us-west-1')

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownServiceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 client = boto3.client(service_name='bedrock-runtime',region_name='us-west-1')

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py:92, in client(*args, **kwargs)
     86 def client(*args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the boto3 1.28.57 version has bedrock service enabled. So I updated the version and it's working fine now. Please find the code https://medium.com/@sanjeebmeister/invoking-llm-models-using-bedrock-from-aws-37ee5d692819